# Ruby class method and instance method

Tags: ruby, class, methods, instance

I am trying to call a method on `File`. I read the documentation of `File` and I see the class `method ::basename`. I tried the following:

```
x = File.new("name_of_file.ext")
x::basename("name_of_file.ext")
```

Why can't I access the class method `::basename` in this way?

Comment: Class methods are accessed off the class.  In your case, you're looking for File.basename(some_file_string).

Comment: ...and to invoke the class method `basename` from an instance you would write `x.class.basename("name_of_file.ext")`, as `x.class #=> File`.

Comment: I have written an answer by making some assumptions about your question, but really, your question is unclear and you should clarify it. Basically, you are asking "Why I can't access to class method ::basename like php ?" and the answer to that is "Because Ruby is Ruby, not PHP."

Comment: FYI `::` is the same as `.` when calling methods, i.e. `o.foo` and `o::foo` are identical.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. Classes are objects like any other object in Ruby. Like any other object in Ruby, they are instances of a class, namely the class `Class`.

So, just like any other object has methods that are defined in its class, classes also have methods that are defined in its class.

That's one half of the story. "Class methods" like `::new` are typically like this. `Class#new` is an instance method of class `Class`, and since `File` is an instance of `Class`, you can call `File.new`.

The other half of the story is that every object in Ruby has a *singleton class*, a class that this object is the only instance of. Since this class has only one instance, any instance methods defined in this singleton class can only be called on that one single object. Since classes are objects like any other object, they have a singleton class like any other object, and methods can be defined there. For example, `File::basename` is defined as an instance method of the singleton class of `File`.

The reason why you cannot call `x.basename` is really simple: `File` and `x` are completely different objects which are instances of completely different classes, so why *would* you expect to be able to call the same method on both? Well, you wouldn't! Different objects that are instances of different classes usually have different methods.

Comment: The OP tried to call it via `x::basename`, not `x.basename`. Probably expecting `::` to be syntactic sugar for `.class.`

Comment: Using `::` for message sends is un-idiomatic, and has surprising behavior if the message starts with a capital letter and takes no argument list, that's why I changed it to `.`. It doesn't matter, though, because in *this* example, they behave identically.